# How can I paginate a dictionary inside my model?

Tags: python, django

I have a model and I have a single page for each one.

```py
class Group(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, db_index=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    members = models.OrderedDictField(default=dict, blank=True)
```

This is an example of a representation of members.

```py
{
    "Jeon Heejin": "Designer",
    "Kim Hyunjin": "Baker",
    "Jo Haseul": "Musician"
}
```

However, when I render a page that represents a group, some groups have more than 100 members. So, I want to paginate it, but I am not getting how to paginate a dictionary that is inside a model.

I also tried to paginate my Views, but nothing had changed.

```py
class GroupView(DetailView):
    template_name = "tailwind/group_detal.html"
    model = Group
    slug_url_kwarg = "group_name"
    slug_field = "name"
    context_object_name = "project"
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        try:
            return Group.objects.get(name=self.kwargs.get("group_name"))
        except Group.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

And this is the way that I am returning my items.

```py
<div class="md:grow mt-6 flex flex-col space-y-8 overflow-x-hidden">

    {% for key, value in project.members.items %}
      <div class="overflow-x-auto">

        <div class="mt-4 px-4 py-4 bg-gray-100 rounded-md font-mono">
          <div class="overflow-auto">
            {{ value | linebreaksbr }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

I am still getting all the items on the same single page, but my goal is to paginate my items for each Group.

I am still getting all the items on the same single page, but my goal is to paginate my items for each Group. I want the group to be spread across multiple pages and the URLs should look like an added query param in the end.

Comment: Django pagination works at the model level, so e.g. it will only paginate a collection of `Group` instances so that there are x Groups per page.  To achieve this _within_ a single Group, on the contents of OrderedDictField, you're going to have to write the pagination logic yourself. Also think about what it means in the front-end to paginate the members of a Group.  Do you want the Group to be spread across multiple pages? What will the urls of those pages look like?  Or do you want a single page with a "pageable" or "scrollable" area on it to save space? That can be implemented in JS

Comment: I want the group to be spread across multiple pages and the URLs should look like an added query param in the end.

Comment: Seems a bit pointless when you have to load all the data from db and then return just some of it. It would maybe be more natural to have `members` as a reverse foreign key to a separate `Member` model, then `some_group.members` would be a queryset that you could paginate with the Django paginator.